# Does Herald of Secret Streams work with +1/+0 or +0/+1 counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have [Herald of Secret Streams](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHerald%20of%20Secret%20Streams%5d), with his ability

> Creatures you control with +1/+1 counters on them can't be blocked.

Say I were to put +1/+0 or +0/+1 on a creature, would Herald's ability still apply or does it have to be a +1/+1?

Comment: Be careful about using terms such as "activate" here; it may make sense in English, but to activate an ability in MTG means something different than what this card does.

Comment: Why do you think it means +1/+0 if it says +1/+1???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, **it has to be a +1/+1 counter**. A counter is a very specific thing, see the [comprehensive rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 121.1a A +X/+Y counter on a creature or on a creature card in a zone other than the battlefield, where X and Y are numbers, adds X to that object’s power and Y to that object’s toughness. Similarly, -X/-Y counters subtract from power and toughness. See rule 613.3.

+1/+0 and +0/+1 counters do not magically combine into +1/+1 counters; the only counters that affect each other are +1/+1 counters and -1/-1 counters:

> 121.3. If a permanent has both a +1/+1 counter and a -1/-1 counter on it, N +1/+1 and N -1/-1 counters are removed from it as a state-based action, where N is the smaller of the number of +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters on it. See rule 704.

Note that +X/+Y counters other than +1/+1 and -1/-1, like +1/+0 and +0/+1, are very rare; those boosts mostly happen as *temporary* effects (i.e. a target creature gains +1/+0 until end of turn). This is entirely different from a counter.

Answer (score 5):

The ability refers specifically to "+1/+1 counters", so that is the only thing is would care about. A creature with a +1/+0 counter, or a +0/+1 counter, would not be affected.

It is worth noting that Magic stopped using +1/+0 and +0/+1 counters. Old cards may still have them, but they haven't been seen on any new cards in a long time. [Here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/11-size-fits-all-2008-02-11) is an article from 2008 explaining this decision.